# What is the second derivative of a B-spline?

Tags: smoothing, splines, polynomial, derivative, calculus

A [B-spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) of degree $j$ is defined at knots $\vec k$ by the Cox-de Boor recursion formula
\begin{align} 
    B_{i,1}(x) &= \left\{
        \begin{matrix} 
            1 & \mathrm{if} \quad k_i \leq x < k_{i+1} \\
            0 & \mathrm{otherwise} 
        \end{matrix}
    \right. \\
    B_{i,j}(x) &= \frac{x - k_i}{k_{i+j-1} - k_i} B_{i,j-1}(x) + \frac{k_{i+j} - x}{k_{i+j} - k_{i+1}} B_{i+1,j-1}(x)
\end{align}

and has derivative
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\text{d}B_{i,j}(x)}{\text{d}x}
    =
    (j-1)
    \left(
        \frac{-B_{i+1,j-1}(x)}{k_{i+j}-k_{i+1}}
        +
        \frac{B_{i,j-1}(x)}{k_{i+j-1}-k_i}
    \right).
\end{equation}

I am trying to implement the O'Sullivan penalty
\begin{equation}
    S(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N \left\{ y_i - \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j B_j(x) \right\}^2 + \lambda \int_x \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j \frac{\text{d}^2 B_j(x)}{\text{d}x^2} \right\} \text{d}x
\end{equation}
which requires second derivatives. What is the second derivative of a B-spline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This document](http://www.stem2.org/je/bspline.pdf) gives (with a corrected typo)

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\text{d}^{(n)}B_{i,j}(x)}{\text{d}x^{(n)}}
    =
    (j-1)
    \left(
        \frac{- \text{d}^{(n-1)} B_{i+1,j-1}(x) / \text{d}x^{(n-1)}}{k_{i+j}-k_{i+1}}
        +
        \frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)} B_{i,j-1}(x) / \text{d}x^{(n-1)}}{k_{i+j-1}-k_i}
    \right).
\end{equation}

Comment: +1. Thank you for sharing your answer with us. Please consider accepting it too if you think it clarifies the issue you raised (no rep-points for self-accepting an answer I am afraid!).